# while loop and printwriter only writes one line to file

Tags: java, file, java.util.scanner, printwriter, println

I have made a code of which gets a bunch of data from different files in a folder, I have then made sure to only look for a certain kind of word in the files. Then I have made sure the code prints out the results in the console.

All the things I have done up till now works perfectly, but here comes the issue. I want the code to also print/write the information to a .txt file. This sort of works, but it only prints one of the many lines from the different files. I am completely sure that there are more that one as the console print shows at least 20 different lines containing the right word. 
I am not completely sure where I have gone wrong, I have also tried to add the `.flush();` right before the `.close();` but it still wont work. I have also tried to add the `pToDocu.close();` underneath the `sc.close();`, but that doesn't work either, as that doesn't even write anything, that just creates a blank file.

So in short the code is supposed to write a bunch of lines, but it only writes one.

```
 public static void lisFilesF(final File folderV) throws IOException {
            PrintWriter pTD = new PrintWriter("eFile.txt");
            for (final File fileEntry : folderV.listFiles()) {
                if (fileEntry.isDirectory()) {
                    listFilesForFolder(fileEntry);    
                } else {
                    System.out.println(fileEntry.getName());
                    try {
                        Scanner sc = new Scanner(fileEntry);
                        while (sc.hasNextLine()) {
                            String s = sc.nextLine();
                            if(s.contains("@"))
                            {
                            System.out.println(s);
                            pTD.println(s);
                            pTD.close();
                            }
                        }
                        sc.close();
                    } catch (Exception e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                }
                }
            }
        }
```

### UPDATE

I have changed the code to now have the `pTD.close();` outside of the while loop like seen below. Only issue is that the file which is created now is blank, it has no information inside it.

```
public static void lisFilesF(final File folderV) throws IOException {
                PrintWriter pTD = new PrintWriter("eFile.txt");
                for (final File fileEntry : folderV.listFiles()) {
                    if (fileEntry.isDirectory()) {
                        listFilesForFolder(fileEntry);    
                    } else {
                        System.out.println(fileEntry.getName());
                        try {
                            Scanner sc = new Scanner(fileEntry);
                            while (sc.hasNextLine()) {
                                String s = sc.nextLine();
                                if(s.contains("@"))
                                {
                                System.out.println(s);
                                pTD.println(s);
                                }
                            }
                            sc.close();
                            pTD.close();
                        } catch (Exception e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                    }
                }
            }
```

Comment: You are closing your PrintWriter (pTD) after the first write. You shouldn't close the PrintWriter until all writing has been done

Comment: I think you are STILL closing your pTD too soon. You opened it before your for-loop. It looks like you need to close it after your for-loop.

Comment: @blackpanda you are a bloody legend! It is working now, thank you very much. 
PS You could make it an answer so I am able to check it off as the right one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are closing the file (`pTD`) after the first time you write to it. You should extract the `close()` call from the loop and move it after it:

```
Scanner sc = new Scanner(fileEntry);
while (sc.hasNextLine()) {
    String s = sc.nextLine();
    if(s.contains("@")) {
        System.out.println(s);
        pTD.println(s);
    }
}
sc.close();
pTD.close();
```

Comment: I appreciate the feedback, I have changed it now, but now it just creates a blank file. Although when running the Java function, for a second the file seems like it has gotten all the info but then it vanishes. I am not completely sure why it does this.

Answer (score 0):

Remove

```
pTD.close();
```

from your while loop. You close your `Print Writer` after the first write

Comment: I appreciate the feedback, I have  made the change, but now the file created is just blank.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you want to commit ALL of those records to your `PrintWriter`. Therefore, your `pTD.close();` needs to be outside of your for loop, since you declared the PrintWriter before your for loop.